# Printing 1 - D array in multiple lines

Tags: c

I am trying to print a 1d array in multiple lines. I want to print the array 8 by 9 format.

```
int main(){
    int rowColm[63];
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<sizeof(rowColm); i++){

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maddy what does 'print array 8 by 9 format' mean? What are you doing with this int vector? is it a bit vector? being each int a vector of 32 positions in a x86 architecture? I ask, because you are using sizeof(rowColm) in your for which is equal to 63*4 = 252

Comment: does that mean 8 lines of 9 elements?

Comment: As in, an 8 x 9 grid.

Comment: You may want to check what `sizeof(rowColm)` evals to before continuing with this. I don't think that means what you think it does.

Comment: When I was growing up, 8 x 9 was 72, but you've only got 63 elements in your array.  Something is going to be unhappy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate approach:

```
int main()
   {
// int rowColm[63];  --Most likely you meant 72, not 63 (8 * 9 = 72)
   int rowColm[8*9];
   int row;
   int col;

   for(row=0; row < 8; ++row)
      {
      for(col=0; col < 9; ++col)
         printf("%d\t", rowColm[(row*9) + col]);
```

No need here for 'sizeof()' as the compiler knows the size of rowColm array objects, and will index appropriately.

```
      printf("\n");
      }

   return 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int rowColm[63];
    int j,  i;
    for(i = 0; i<(sizeof(rowColm)/sizeof(rowColm[0])); i+=8)
    {
        for(j = i; (j < i+8) && (j < (sizeof(rowColm)/sizeof(rowColm[0]))); j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", rowColm[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not put the `i += 8` in the first loop control?  It is better to have all the loop control stuff in the `for` loops; otherwise, you may as well use a `while` loop.  Otherwise, pretty neat for N lines with 8 values on each line.  You do avoid going beyond the end of the array.

Comment: good point. that was the stupid mistake, the result of changing things mid stream  I'll make the change.